# Error on trying to add Private key with SHA-2 to AWS Opsworks

Tags: amazon-web-services, github, github-actions, aws-opsworks

I am using OpsWorks Chef 11, it was working fine till 15 march 2022.

now getting:

ERROR: You’re using an RSA key with SHA-1, which is no longer allowed. Please use a newer client or a different key type.
Please see Improving Git protocol security on GitHub | The GitHub Blog 2 for more information.

fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

I recreated Key with SHA-2 and updated in Github but unable to update in OpsWorks.

Is there any way to pass new SHA-2 key to OpsWorks?

Comment: Is there any way I can deploy new key and .ssh/config file on server using OpsWorks Stack Custom Json

Comment: I believe we're having the same issue on some old stacks we don't keep very up-to-date.  Now we can't deploy them at all.  Anybody have any ideas?  Do we just need to migrate completely off of OpsWorks?

Answer (score 2):

If You mean accessing a GitHub repository using an SSH URL from OpsWork, then the relevant documentation would be "[AWS OpsWorks/ Using Git Repository SSH Keys](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/opsworks/latest/userguide/workingapps-deploykeys.html)".

Reminder: AWS OpsWorks Stacks does not support SSH key passphrases.

Enter the private key in the Repository SSH Key box when you add [an app or specify cookbook repository](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/opsworks/latest/userguide/workingapps-creating.html). Select `Git` under `Source Control`.